# winsock printing too much

Tags: c++, character, send, receiver

I wanted to try a server/client connection kind of thing, and so I modified the code from a YouTube tutorial (New to C++). So far everything works just fine, except when I try to print the message that was sent by the client.

The code used for sending and receiving data is the following:

```
char buf[4096];

while (true)
{
    ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);

    int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);
    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cerr << "Error in recv()! Quitting" << endl;
        break;
    }

    if (bytesReceived == 0)
    {
        cout << "Client disconnected!" << endl;
        break;
    }

    cout << buf << endl;
    send(clientSocket, buf, bytesReceived + 1, 0);
}
```

Sending it back works fine, as well a printing it to the console. However, in the console it prints a crazy amount of new lines after the initial output. I guess it has something to do with the size of the `buf`, which is 4096, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recv()` tells you how many bytes were actually put into your `buf`, but you are ignoring that value when printing the contents of `buf`.  The `operator<<` you are using expects a null-terminated string, but `recv()` does not guarantee your `buf` is null-terminated (even if the client sends a null terminator, it may not have arrived yet when `recv()` exits).

Use `write()` instead of `operator<<` when printing `buf` to `std::cout`, so that you can specify `bytesReceived` as the size to print.

You are also sending 1 more byte back to the client then you actually received. You should not be adding `+1` to `bytesReceived` when calling `send()`.

You also need to take into account that `send()` may accept fewer bytes for transmission than you ask for, so it needs to be called in a loop, just like with `recv()`.

Try this instead:

```
char buf[4096], *ptr;
int bytesReceived, bytesSent, errCode;

while (true)
{
    bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        errCode = WSAGetLastError();
        cerr << "Error " << errCode << " in recv()! Quitting" << endl;
        break;
    }

    if (bytesReceived == 0)
    {
        cout << "Client disconnected!" << endl;
        break;
    }

    cout.write(buf, bytesReceived);
    //cout << endl;

    ptr = buf;
    while (bytesReceived > 0)
    {
        bytesSent = send(clientSocket, ptr, bytesReceived, 0);
        if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            errCode = WSAGetLastError();
            cerr << "Error " << errCode << " in send()! Quitting" << endl;
            break;
        }
        ptr += byteSent;
        bytesReceived -= byteSent;
   }

   if (bytesReceived > 0)
       break;
}
```

Comment: Thatks, that did what i wanted. But how would i read the message inside the program itself f.e. `if (bytesReceived == "some string") { ... }`?

Comment: @Zuckerpapa you can use `strncmp()` or similar function, or you can convert `buf` to a `std::string` to use its `operator==` or `compare()` method. But, the bigger issue is knowing when to stop reading so you can then compare what you have received. TCP is a byte stream with no concept of messages, so the data itself has to tell you when you have received a full message. There are only 2 ways to do that - by sending the message's size before the message's data, or by terminating the message with a unique delimiter. The protocol you are implementing dictates which approach is used.